# создание свого сайта на GitHub Pages

Tags: github

Как сделать переходы по ссылкам с созданного ресурса username.github.io на остальные работы, которые расположены в моем репозитории на GitHub?

Comment: Может быть ставить ссылкам абсолютные пути. Если бы вы показали ваш профиль гитхаба и пример, что хотите получить, то получили бы более развернутый ответ.

Comment: https://github.com/mkletsko - мой профиль. Создал свой сайт https://mkletsko.github.io. Там есть ссылки на мои работы, которые так же расположены в моем репозитории. Хочется что бы при клике на ссылки открывались рабочие страницы в браузере с моих остальных разделов гитхаба. Если указываю абсолютный путь (например: https://github.com/mkletsko/handylife), то открывается репозиторий на гитхабе. Если указываю ссылку в форме https://mkletsko.github.io/handylife, то 404 ошибка. Надеюсь доступно объяснил :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы продемонстрировать свою работу репозитория `github.com/mkletsko/handylife`, нужно создать ему github page. Сделать это можно по [инструкции](https://pages.github.com) (pages.github.com > Project site > Start from scratch). После того, как сделаете проекту gh page, ссылка на его демонстрацию будет иметь вид `mkletsko.github.io/handylife`, эту ссылку вставить на mkletsko.github.io вместо той, что есть сейчас.

Comment: Супер, все получилось! Спасибо большое!!!